# Database Design for Lord of the rings

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, nosql

I have to design a database for a application game in which there is a path in which in between any number of people can join at a time(lets say ti) , any number of people can leave in between and can again join later on , any number of people can die at ti .

So I have design a nosql database to answer following questions efficiently :-

1. List of people who are present at time ti .
2. List of people who never left till time ti
3. List of people who never died at time ti .

One of the solution could be event based logging , events being "joined","died" ,"left" respectively .

At each event I would be creating a document and then query across the data to answer all the questions .

Second option could be to maintain separate document for each person and update  their details . This will lead to maintaining an array inside the document for joined and left datetime .

Is there any more opimized solution for this problem ?

Comment: We don't do homework questions or job interview questions... Besides why is MySQL tagged when you need to design a no-sql database.

Comment: Sorry about the tagging thing . But I think this is reallife problem and will help the community to increase problem solving skills

Comment: Hi @RaymondNijland , I have changed my question

Comment: Consider what entities you have. You have `character` and `event`. The state of a character at time `ti` can be found in the event matching their character id with the highest timestamp smaller than `ti`. Someone will be willing to help, but I suggest you make a start on this first.